# Problem ins getting notification by urbanAirShip

Tags: apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I have used UrbanAirShip for APNS ,before today i was receiving notification regularly .but today I am not able to receive notification though urbanAir displays message the " Okay, we sent that message."
but I am not getting that on device
please help

Comment: Haha :P For your sake, I hope this was a joke ;)